# Disappear object on mouse click on that object in javascript. In my case I want to disappear a bouncing ball on the click of the mouse

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disappear a moving 2D ball on the click of the mouse. And also I want to do the same on the touch event if it is on the screen touch environment. The problem is that the balls keep moving in the random direction and I want to hide the ball whom I click on.

I used Javascript as I have already mentioned and here is the code which I used to draw ball.
function beginDrawCircle(a,b,color){

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(a, b, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

}

I am providing an extra  information that I have created three such balls now the click on any one of the ball it should disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the ball an IMG, DIV or some other tag? If so, why not add an onclick event handler and set its display to none?

```
<img src="ball.png" id="ball" onclick="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

Comment: Nope the ball is not the png it is drawn on the canvas using arc(a, b, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);

Comment: @AlgorithmFreak it's important that you specify your project conditions **in your question**

Comment: function beginDrawCircle(a,b,color){
 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(a, b, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath(); 
    
}   This is code I used to draw a ball now on the mouse click i would like to disappear it.

Comment: @fixmycode what project condition you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this :

```
document.getElementById("ball").onclick = foo;
foo(){
this.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify if you were working with jQuery or something like that, a solution in pure Javascript could be:

```
//Assuming all the balls are of class ".ball"
var balls = document.querySelectorAll(".ball");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(balls, function(ball){
    ball.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        ball.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

Comment: What project condition are you expecting